# Production Sound + Foley

Tags: foley, production-sound, production-audio, foley-editing

I'm working on a movie, whats played in a forest. All the steps on the leafs are really pregnant in the production sound and of course in the dialog to. We record foleys for the movie, but i don't think so, i could use together (steps).

Whats the method in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Are the leaves causing problems with the dialogue or are you just wondering if you can mix production FX with sound FX?

If the production sound is a problem you could attempt using Izotope RX. The Decrackler module may help.

If you're just looking to add the sound FX,, I would use them subtly to enhance the production FX. Try and match the timbre of the real leaves.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yes, i use izotope a lot, i should unfortunately.
i would mix together, but the problem is it sound a little bit different.